# PDFBox doesn't embedd all Fonts

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfbox

i'm using PDFBox in C# Project to create PDF/A and PDF/A3. Almost everything is working except that when I use PDFBox to convert a normal PDF-File to PDF/A not all Fonts are embedded. If I use Word to save as PDF/A the Font in Question is embedded. How do I embedd ArialMT too?

[image: Normal PDF-File converted to PDF/A]

[image: PDF/A-File created by Word]

```
private PDDocumentCatalog makeDocPDFAcompliant(String producer, String creator)
{
PDDocumentCatalog cat = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
PDMetadata metadata = new PDMetadata(doc);
cat.setMetadata(metadata);

List<Dictionary<string, PDFont>> lstFonts = new List<Dictionary<string, PDFont>>();
List<PDFont> lstPDFonts= new List<PDFont>();

List pages = cat.getAllPages();
Iterator it = pages.iterator();

while (it.hasNext())
{
    PDPage page = (PDPage)it.next();
    var pageFont = page.getResources().getFonts();
    lstFonts.Add(pageFont.ToDicitonary<string, PDFont>());
}

foreach (Dictionary<string, PDFont> d in lstFonts)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, PDFont> entry in d)
    {
        PDFont font = entry.Value;

        if (!lstPDFonts.Contains(font))
        {
            lstPDFonts.Add(font);
        }
    }
}

//PDType0Font font0 = PDType0Font.Load(doc,)

XMPMetadata xmp = new XMPMetadata();
XMPSchemaPDFAId pdfaid = new XMPSchemaPDFAId(xmp);
xmp.addSchema(pdfaid);
pdfaid.setConformance("A");
pdfaid.setPart(java.lang.Integer.valueOf(1));
pdfaid.setAbout("");
metadata.importXMPMetadata(xmp);

//System.IO.Stream asset = Zaumzeug.Properties.Resources.sRGB_Color_Space_Profile

System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Zaumzeug.Properties.Resources.sRGB_Color_Space_Profile);
InputStream colorProfile = new ikvm.io.InputStreamWrapper(stream);

PDOutputIntent oi = new PDOutputIntent(doc, colorProfile);
oi.setInfo("sRGB IEC61966-2.1");
oi.setOutputCondition("sRGB IEC61966-2.1");
oi.setOutputConditionIdentifier("sRGB IEC61966-2.1");
oi.setRegistryName("http://www.color.org");
cat.addOutputIntent(oi);

doc.save(@"D:\Examples .Net\Data\FontsNormalA.pdf");


return cat;
}
```

Comment: in PDFBox 2.0.11 try `resources.put(fontName, PDTrueTypeFont.load(doc, new File("arial.ttf"), WinAnsiEncoding.INSTANCE)` if you know that it is arial. However be aware that converting PDF to PDF/A is more than just that. There are several commercial tools for this because it is so tricky.

Comment: Is it just me? I see you build up `lstPDFonts` but you seem to never use it?

Comment: Yes, because i'm not sure how to use it. Because all Fonts are embedded but ArialMT.

Comment: You wrote you *"create PDF/A"*. Do you create them from scratch or from existing pdfs? In the former case you have a chance, in the latter case hardly so.